# Performing Complex Curl request in Node

Tags: node.js, curl, jenkins

I am looking to build a curl step into a node program (that I normally use for Jenkins). I have looked at the curl documentation but I am unsure as how to incorporate the following steps

> **Retrieve crumb**

```
CRUMB =$(curl -s 'http://admin:TOKEN@localhost:8080/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)');
```

> **POST**

```
curl -I -X POST http://USER:TOKEN@localhost:8080/job/JOBNAME/build -H “Jenkins-Crumb:crumnumber”
```

Comment: are you trying to invoke curl from node or recreate the functionality using an http request in node?

Comment: I would be happy to try either, but I am not sure how to pass the extra parms like concat in the first retrieve crumb request.